# Basement wall framing

Tags: framing

I'm going to start work on a basement bathroom.  I've got the drains already in.  Will insulate the walls with foam boards....the framing?   Wood or metal?   I'm thinking with a basement and the possibility of moisture I should just go with metal framing to be safe?

Comment: to be safe you should make the basement dry.

Answer (score 3):

At least in the US, wood framing is far more common than metal in residential construction. And, I think, a lot easier for DIY construction. Certainly much easier when it comes to hanging cabinets and a lot of other little (and not-so-little) details.

If water is a problem with your wood frame construction then you have **much** more serious problems as your walls will be rotting, mold growing, etc. long before your wood frame gets damaged.